# Directory that lets anyone do anything to everything regardless of creator

Tags: permissions, posix

This is for FreeBSD UFS, but I would expect that it's applicable to any type of POSIX style filesystem.

Here's the context:

- An external volume formatted as UFS.
- There are multiple FreeBSD workstations, each configured in their own way by the user who owns them.
- For `$REASONS`, networking and file sharing over NFS, Samba, etc. are not an option.

The external volume is passed along from one user to the other, each user works with the data on the volume, and requires full access to read, write, and execute that data.  Users will create new files and folders.  They will regularly delete and modify files and folders.

The common group approach is not going to work since the IDs may differ between systems. I've already tried setting open permissions like 777, I tried ACLs, I briefly looked into sticky bits.  None of these solutions worked.  I would run into a problem where USER A would create a file but USER B is unable to modify it.

On NTFS there is this concept of "Everyone" and setting that to "Full control".  How can I get a similar behaviour with a POSIX file system like UFS?

EDIT: (clarify why the 777 approach fails).

```
john@pc1 /mnt# sudo chmod 777 /media/external_usb/
john@pc1 /mnt# ls -larths /media/external_usb/
total 18
 1 drwxrwxrwx  2 john  john     2B Dec 16 12:41 ./
17 drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel     9B Dec 16 12:41 ../

john@pc1 ~> touch /media/external_usb/test
john@pc1 ~> ls -larths /media/external_usb/test
1 -rw-r--r--  1 john  john     0B Dec 16 12:43 /media/external_usb/test

# Drive is moved from pc1 to pc2

adam@pc2 ~> touch /media/external_usb/test
touch: /media/external_usb/test: Permission denied
```

Comment: Could you explain why setting the permissions to 777 didn't work?

Comment: Any new items created afterwards would use the umask as set by the user's system (0022).  So USER A would create a file and it would default to permissions 644, preventing USER B from modifying the file.

Comment: In that case, a combination of 777 and ACLs for file creation in the target directory should be enough. Can you please [edit] your question and explain what you tried and how it failed so we don't give you the same suggestions?

Comment: I was struggling with this (but then I did not need it). I was about to set up all the umasks to be more open for group. We already have a personal group as our default group for all users, so this will not increase permission, until we change the file's group, or add ACLs. Then I was going to add default ACLs.  (I never got around to testing or using)

Comment: Have you tried `chmod --recursive` instead?  But then every user would need to do that before unmounting the disk...

Comment: Note: if you centrally manage your users laptop and can ensure the same group exists on all their machines with the exact same GID, then the group-based approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

While you are setting the directory permissions to 777, each user's file within the directory are still owned by that user/group -- specifically their UID:GID.  AND, the file permissions don't allow "anyone" to change the file.  In your example, the file is only rw by john even though the directory the file is in is accessible by anyone.

To do what you want, before the drive is moved to another system, john would need to set the permissions on the file to 666 (rw by anyone).  Highly insecure, but apparently what you're stuck with.

If you really want people to be able to execute the file, then you would need to set the permissions on the file to 777 instead of 666.

This isn't a BSD or UFS issue... you would have the same problem on nearly any UNIX OS & filesystem.

Comment: A removable media is already insecure. What you need to do (for security) is mount with no-suid, no-dev, etc The rest will just give a false sense of security.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the effect of using `nosuid` in this case would be that programs will ignore the UID and GID information on files and directories, thus allowing read/write access to all the items regardless of what owners and permissions are already set?  If that is true, then this is an acceptable solution.